# Connecting LEDs with least pins and wiring

Tags: gpio, led

I want to connect 5 leds (red, blue, green, yellow and white) to my raspberry Pi.

Only 1 led will be lit at a given point in time.

Is it possible  to connect them all to a single GPIO port and using 1 resistor?

If this is possible, would they need to be in series or in parallel?

I've seen many examples online but I'm confused. I read about charlieplexing but that seems to overcomplicate things (and for some reason it didn't even have a connection to ground)

Comment: Not Pi specific.

Comment: `would they need to be in series or in parallel?` ... why are those the only options? ... both series and parallel connections would light all the LEDs at the same time

Comment: `for some reason it didn't even have a connection to ground` ... why would a ground connection be required? ... to light a LED, you need a voltage difference across the LED

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to connect them all to a single GPIO port and using 1 resistor?

Yes, but without additional hardware, when one is lit, they will all be lit. Which is the same thing as saying, "When the GPIO is ON, it is ON, and when it is OFF, it is OFF."

[*Charlieplexing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charlieplexing) is interesting, but strikes me personally as an esoteric solution looking for a problem :)  But rest assured that *Charlieplexing* is incapable of violating the laws of physics, and there will **always** be a non-zero potential difference between pins before current will flow & an LED is lit. There is no GND identified in the [schematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:2-pin_Charlieplexing_with_common_resistor.svg) because the voltages at X1 and X2 are *reversed* to realize the *Charlieplexer*. AFAIK, this is not possible with RPi GPIO pins, and even if it were, it's still 2 or more GPIOs.

Your objective of `Connecting LEDs with least pins and wiring` may be more practically reached with an *external* hardware component similar to the [ADG2188](https://www.analog.com/en/products/adg2188.html) - an 8 channel analog switch matrix with an i2c interface. Or, better still, per @joan's comment, get a [PCA9685 - 16-channel LED controller](https://www.nxp.com/products/power-management/lighting-driver-and-controller-ics/ic-led-controllers/16-channel-12-bit-pwm-fm-plus-ic-bus-led-controller:PCA9685) that also has an i2c interface. However, the i2c interface still requires 2 GPIO pins.

Comment: If you go that route just get a PCA9685 based servo driver board. It is s LED driver after all.

Answer (score 1):

No, it s not possible.  You need 5 GPIO.

Answer (score 0):

They make devices called 1 wire LED WS2812B. Look at this link, it shows how to connect to an Arduino with power, ground, signal: https://www.arrow.com/en/research-and-events/articles/protocol-for-the-ws2812b-programmable-led. There are examples online on how to program this device.

Comment: Interesting article, and thanks for sharing that, but your answer seems to be a reference to what someone else wrote. The SE guidance for that is [How to reference material written by others](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/referencing)